# Splitting a List<string> on the basis of comman ( ,) delimiter and handling NUmberformat exception

Tags: java, string

I have the following method applyIncentives which takes ListlstIds

```
public void applyIncentives(List<String> lstIds) throws Exception {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    String pricingTierId = null;
    if (lstIds != null && lstIds.size() > 0) {
        for (String lstpricingTierIds : lstIds) {
            pricingTierId = lstpricingTierIds.trim();            
        }
    }

    try {
        session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from customer.apply_incentives(:pricingTierId)");
        query.setString("pricingTierId", pricingTierId);
        query.list();

        tx.commit();
        approveFlag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception", ex);
    }
    finally {
        if (session != null)
            session.close();
    }
    return approveFlag;
}
```

I'm passing the `pricingTierId` from lstIds and passing to the stored proc which accepts  an Integer.

While debugging the **value of lstIds is "52512,85822"** two `pricingTierId's` separated by comma (,).

Before passing the `pricingTierId` to the stored Proc I have written the following:

```
String pricingTierId = null ;
if (lstIds != null && lstIds.size() > 0) {
    for (String lstpricingTierIds : lstIds) {
        pricingTierId = lstpricingTierIds.trim();            
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. How to split the `pricingTierId` by delimited comma (,)?
   Since I'm passing List `List<String> lstIds` I can't use `pricingTierId = lstpricingTierIds.trim().split(",")` directly.
2. If I change `String pricingTierId = null`  to `String[] pricingTierId`  then 
   I have error at `query.setString("pricingTierId", pricingTierId);`
   If I use `query.setInteger("pricingTierId", Integer.parseInt(pricingTierId));` then I get **Numberformat Exception** since comma(,) gets passed to the stored proc.

Added the code as suggested

```
List<String> pricingTierId = null;
if (lstIds != null && lstIds.size() > 0) {
    for(String lstpricingTierIds : lstIds) {
        pricingTierId = Arrays.asList(lstpricingTierIds.trim().split(","));
    }
}
```

However I'm getting the error at:

```
query.setString("pricingTierId", pricingTierId);
```

setString cannot be used for `String[]`

and I cannot use `query.setInteger("pricingTierId", Integer.parseInt(pricingTierId));`
as it says change the type of `pricingTierId` to `String`.

Comment: How are you going to pass 2 id's into the one query? Even if it is split there is only one parameter from `pricingTierId` in the query.

Comment: You could split the string by comma and then pass individual elements to the query in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about getting it out of the array created from a split and then loop around:

```
String[] pricingTierIdArray = lstpricingTierIds.trim().split(",");
for(String s : pricingTierIdArray ) {
    query.setInteger("pricingTierId", Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

The `setInteger()` method would overwrite the previous value. Unless you change the query only one id can be set.

Or simply just:

```
String pricingTierIdArray = lstpricingTierIds.trim().split(",")[0]; //This depends on whether you need both values or not.
```

Comment: Good to hear it @ronan!